# How to get any Youtube channel's subscribed users list and their details using YouTube Analytics API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to get any youtube channel's subscribed users list and their detail(analysis), like the XYZ channel has 45% male users subscriber and 55% female users subscriber, this channel was subscribed by this top 5 countries subscriber and the channel Audience Demography related information.

For this, I use YouTube Analytics API v3 and my URL is like

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet,contentDetails,subscriberSnippet&key=APIKEY&id=CHANNELID

but this URL return below code in response

```
{
    {
      "kind": "youtube#SubscriptionListResponse",
      "etag": "TOmVRCZpu2meG82Dv9k7Y-QQ8t888",
      "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 0,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
   },
   "items": []
}
```

I don't know I'm right or wrong for the use of this URL for getting the above detail. I did read all the questions about youtube data API but I did not find my question's answer on those questions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of data you are requesting falls under the private data of a channel. You can only access such data if you are the owner of that channel (by authorizing - Oauth2) or if the channel owner lets you access that data (after going through authorization) through a publicly available application.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list), if your intention is to obtain subscriptions info w.r.t. a given channel -- identified by its channel ID --, then you should use the parameter [`channelId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#channelId):

> **channelId** (string)
>
> The channelId parameter specifies a YouTube channel ID. The API will only return that channel's subscriptions.

Therefore, do change your URL above to:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet,contentDetails,subscriberSnippet&key=APIKEY&channelId=CHANNELID`.

Comment: Thanks, @stvar, the above URL is working after channelId parameter change but can you please tell me I am right or this way is right for searching subscriber's data?

Comment: As far as I know, the kind of data you're expecting from YouTube Data API (channel's user sex, country of origin, and other such info) is not available via API endpoints. Of course, Google can actually deduce and attach such info to any given channel, but, again, as far as I know, this kind of *sensitive* data is not made available to the common users/developers base.